# How to setup foreign keys for models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having difficulties finding the right combination to setup my foreign keys. No matter what I do my console is still reading zip_ids when it should be zip_codes only.

I am receiving this in the console:

```
Zip.code(30052).users.count
  Zip Load (12.5ms)  SELECT `zips`.* FROM `zips` WHERE `zips`.`code` = 30052 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`zip_code` = 12859
 => 0
```

The issue is the second line where it is somehow pulling zip code 12859, which I never specified. This is because it is using zip_id instead of zip_code from the user table.

zip.rb:

```
 has_many :users,  :foreign_key => "zip_code"
```

user.rb :

```
  belongs_to :zip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the code as your primary key

```
class Zip < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'code'
  has_many :users, foreign_key: 'zip_code'
end
```

Don't forget to add a unique index to the code column:

```
class AddIndexToZipsCode < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :zips, :code, unique: true
  end
end
```

And validate the uniqueness of `code`

```
# zip.rb
validates :code, uniqueness: true
```

Then you will find a zip `Zip.find(code)`

Add an index to `zip_code` on your `users` table.

```
class AddIndexToUsersZipCode < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, :zip_code
  end
end
```

Now, `Zip.find(code).users.count` should work.

To get the reverse relationship working (`user.zip`), you need to specify the foreign_key in the association:

```
# user.rb
belongs_to :zip, foreign_key: :zip_code
```

Comment: I did that prior to coming here. If I have both foreign keys then I get the same issue. If I remove foreign key from zips I get, "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'users.zip_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`zip_id` = 12859".

Comment: That's strange... Do you care about the `id` of zip? Otherwise, you may want to use `code` as the `primary_key`. So your users table has a `zip_id` column as well as a `zip_code`? Maybe that's what is confusing Rails...

Comment: I wouldn't think adding a new column should be a requirement for it to work. I don't care for the id of the zip at all, and I'm about to remove it from the table. Which removal now gives zip_code = NULL

Comment: Thank you. Will have to study this some more to understand it in full.